# How to disable the "Windows" key but not "Windows + any" key?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Windows Key from Opening Start Menu in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/151304/prevent-windows-key-from-opening-start-menu-in-windows-7)

I want to disable the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key but not <kbd>Windows</kbd>+any key.

For reasons that I use some software to let <kbd>Windows</kbd>+other key to open some program, but when I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, it will pull out a Start menu which is boring me much.

How to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use autohot key

> I wanted to find a way to disable the start menu popup but still leave
>   shortcuts like Win+R and Win+L enabled. I messed around for 2 hours
>   trying to figure out a solution and finally stumbled on a 2-line
>   solution:
>
> ~LWin Up:: return ~RWin Up:: return
>
> This seems to work on both XP and 7. Haven't tried Vista, but I don't
>   see any reason it wouldn't work.

[Source](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/51631-disable-windows-key-start-menu-but-not-shortcuts/)